# Add a list column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with that has the two biggest cities in each country in Europe. I want to make a column as a list of the two cities put together. below is an example of how the dataset looks.

```
Country  BiggestCity   SecondBiggestCity
England  London        Birmingham
Spain    Madrid        Barcelona
Sweden   Stockholm     Gothenburg
Germany  Berlin        Frankfurt
```

This is what I've tried:

```
df['BothCities'] = df['BiggestCity'] + df['SecondBiggestCity']
```

but it doesnt give me the desired output. I would like to add an additional column `BothCities` which would have the two cities in a list.

Desired Output:

```
Country  BiggestCity   SecondBiggestCity   BothCities
England  London        Birmingham          [London, Birmingham]
Spain    Madrid        Barcelona           [Madrid, Barcelona]
Sweden   Stockholm     Gothenburg          [Stockholm, Gothenburg]
Germany  Berlin        Frankfurt           [Berlin, Frankfurt]
```

Any recommendations on how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df['BothCities'] = df[['BiggestCity', 'SecondBiggestCity']].values.tolist()

print(df)

   Country BiggestCity SecondBiggestCity               BothCities
0  England      London        Birmingham     [London, Birmingham]
1    Spain      Madrid         Barcelona      [Madrid, Barcelona]
2   Sweden   Stockholm        Gothenburg  [Stockholm, Gothenburg]
3  Germany      Berlin         Frankfurt      [Berlin, Frankfurt]
```

No need for it but if you wanted to solve it your way you could achieve it like this:

What you have tried is only part of your goal. You just concatenate two strings to one big string. You would concatenate them with a separator (e.g `'/'`)

```
df['BothCities'] = df['BiggestCity'] + '/' + df['SecondBiggestCity']
```

and then split it to a list based on that separator

```
df['BothCities'] = df['BothCities'].str.split('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need concat with list

```py
df['BothCities'] = df['BiggestCity'].apply(lambda x: [x]) + df['SecondBiggestCity'].apply(lambda x: [x])
```

Or you can try `apply` `list` on rows

```py
df['BothCities'] = df[['BiggestCity', 'SecondBiggestCity']].apply(list, axis=1)
```

```
print(df)

   Country BiggestCity SecondBiggestCity               BothCities
0  England      London        Birmingham     [London, Birmingham]
1    Spain      Madrid         Barcelona      [Madrid, Barcelona]
2   Sweden   Stockholm        Gothenburg  [Stockholm, Gothenburg]
3  Germany      Berlin         Frankfurt      [Berlin, Frankfurt]
```

You can also try with `zip`

```py
df['BothCities'] = list(map(list, zip(df['BiggestCity'], df['SecondBiggestCity'])))
```

Comment: For performance-wise, I think the last method is the fastest compared to all the methods?

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew Not sure, didn't test this.

Comment: Tried them all with 1000 rows of data just now, yes the last method is the fastest among all :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want it simple, you can do a simple list comprehension with zip.

```
df["BothCities"] = [[i,j]for i,j in zip(df['BiggestCity'],df['SecondBiggestCity'])]
```

Or tuple for faster performance

```
df["BothCities"] = tuple([i,j]for i,j in zip(df['BiggestCity'],df['SecondBiggestCity']))
```

For your reference (with 1000 rows of data)

```
%timeit [[i,j]for i,j in zip(df['BiggestCity'],df['SecondBiggestCity'])]
304 µs ± 9.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit tuple([i,j]for i,j in zip(df['BiggestCity'],df['SecondBiggestCity']))
298 µs ± 6.66 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```